# MYSQL Exporting and Importing table's data

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I'm building an archival process for an AWS MySQL RDS which will run from an EC2 instance via php. The steps are

1. To export the selected not all of the data from a table, query has some JOIN queries as well in order to find the right records

```
mysql -B -uroot -proot database_name -e "select a.* from api_response a LEFT JOIN user u on u.user_id=a.user_id where u.first_name LIKE 'ab%' LIMIT 100000;" | sed "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\\\n/\n/g;s/\\\t/\t/g" > "C:\xampp\htdocs\tmp\a.txt"
```

2. The exported file is uploaded to S3 bucket
3. Restoring the archived data to the table using below command downloading it from s3 in the background

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\temp.txt' IGNORE INTO TABLE `api_response` CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '
' IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Currently I'm facing issue in escaping the characters in the sed command and that leads to inaccurate data restoration. RDS doesn't really support the **OUTFILE** command and that's why I've looked into other options, also **mysqldump** doesn't allow JOINS so can't use that either.

I was trying to export data using below command and wanted something like a csv file with proper escaping.

```
mysql -B -uroot -proot database_name -e "select a.* from api_response a LEFT JOIN user u on u.user_id=a.user_id where u.first_name LIKE 'ab%' LIMIT 100000;" | sed "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\\\n/\n/g;s/\\\t/\t/g" > "C:\xampp\htdocs\tmp\a.txt"
```

the export worked however the character escaping didn't really work and when used the `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE..`  the data was incorrectly imported in the table

Comment: If you are only using joined tables in `WHERE` part of query, you can rewrite `JOIN` as subquery instead. That will allow you to use `mysqldump`.

Comment: @MichalHynčica The subqueries can have millions of records to be used in an IN query and that can lead to memory issues

Comment: You can use `EXISTS` instead of `IN`. For the condition in your example: `user_id IS NULL OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.user_id = api_response.user_id AND user.first_name LIKE 'ab%')`. The part `user_id IS NULL OR` is there because you were using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in your example.

Comment: @MichalHynčica Thanks for the suggestion, but there's a bit more complexity and multiple JOINS that I need to use. 
For now I'm creating a csv file via php where first row is of the column names and the rest  is of data optionally enclosed by double quotes, and if there is any value===`NULL`  then i'm adding the NULL string in the csv, but if a column has a string NULL then I have to change it slighly e.g NuLL so that during restore it isn't inserted as NULL. 
and to Load the data i'm using `CHARACTER SET UTF8 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ESCAPED BY '"' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' IGNORE 1 LINES`